# Expanding a DIV with an Unordered List

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking at having an unordered list that filters through some of my work.  I have the filter working perfectly fine (not in this example) and I am now at the stage where I am having difficulty styling it.  I've tried setting the width of the div and doing some online research but to no success.

It currently looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/

What I am hoping for is that only two words are displayed initially (Filter and All) and when the user hovers over or clicks on the word "Filter", the list expands with a CSS width-transition to display the other categories (Web, Still, Motion and Games).  So, from this:

***Filter | All***

to this:

***Filter | Web | Still | Motion | Games***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

### Here is final version with animation and fixed line-height bug: http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/9/

Another solution, without animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/4/

What to do:

1. Put filters in separate nested UL
2. Set it's display to inline.
3. On document ready hide filters
4. On click toggle display property.

This solution is not buggy like the one provided by @PeterSzymkowski and looks nicer than @Duopixel's solution (which is anyway good and may be still suitable for you if you prefer animation of that kind when items appear outsite the right enge of the page and run into the position).

UPDATE:

Here is animated version, few changes made, check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/7/

Comment: Looking forward to seeing the final result Ihor - paspar2.com

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/5/ - here is working animation, but need some time to figure out how to make it hidden by default. So far several methods failed - it works but the first time you click there's no animation. Will post an update when done. I need this effect for one of my projects as well so I'll make it work :)

Comment: @Rob, check my updated answer for final animated example. Haven't tested it in all browsers, but might work. Here's direct link: http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/7/

Comment: Simply beautiful Ihor...I really appreciate that you've gone to a great effort in answering my question.  
Your method seems to give a better transition over the previous suggestions (dealing with the opacity and overflow issues).  Do you know of a way to make the list collapse after a certain time (if it is inactive or not in use)?  
I tested it in Safari and Modzilla/Firefox, where in FF there seems to be a nested list issue (a text drop) on the first and last word...any thoughts in tackling this just let me know and I'll tick this answer off

Comment: @Rob, yeah, that was a line-height issue appearing in FF, Safari and Opera while working fine in Chrome. Now fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/9/

Comment: And about collapsing after some time - yes, this is posiible. When opening a submenu we can start a timer. When we click any filter (for example, Web), we can add a class '.currentsub' to it. After timer is out we can check it any subnav items has '.currentsub' class. If has - we do nothing, if not - collapse the menu. Need help with this?

Comment: If it's not too much trouble Ihor, the more help the better. I modified the version to this: http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/12/ just to avoid the text clipping. And again, really well done and thanks for all your hard work.

Answer (score 6):

It is better if you nest your `ul`'s such as...

```
<div id="portfolionav">
    <ul class="filter">
        <li>Filter</li>
        <ul class="subfilters">
           <li class="web"><a href="#">Web</a></li>
           <li class="still"><a href="#">Still</a></li>
           <li class="motion"><a href="#">Motion</a></li>
           <li class="games"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li class="current all"><a href="#">All</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>​
```

The CSS changes for transitions are quite straightforward:

```
#portfolionav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;

}
#portfolionav ul ul {width: 0; opacity: 0;}

#portfolionav ul:hover > ul {width: 370px; opacity: 1;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jukUm/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Duopixel.  Appreciate your suggestion and will most likely use this method, depending on Ihor's reply.

Comment: I agree, good idea, voted up. Unfortunately, limited to recent browser versions.

Answer (score 2):

Split `ul.filter` into two `ul`'s and use some code:

```
$('#expand').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.filter.hidden').show();
    var tw = $('.filter.hidden').width();
    $('.filter.hidden').css('width', '0px');
    $('.filter.hidden').animate({width: tw+'px'});

});
```

- Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XcVHU/3/ (click on filter)

Comment: Another fantastic way of achieving the results I am after...thanks Peter.